# One hot encoding a multi-valued categorical column where not all categories are represented

Tags: pandas, dummy-variable

I have a column in a dataset called 'Crop', that represents the crops grown in a field over a period of time. The column might have a single string, like Cotton, or it may have multiple strings, like Cotton, Soy. And, depending on the dataset, there may be crops that are categories, but not represented in the particular dataset I'm training with at the time.

I've tried this:

```
possible_categories = list(['Corn', 'Sorghum', 'Hemp', 'Cotton', 'Soy'])

#df = (X.Crop).str.split(', ', expand=True)
#ohe_crop = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=possible_categories, sparse=True)
#print(ohe_crop)

X.Crop = (X.Crop).astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=possible_categories))

ohe_crop = pd.get_dummies(X.Crop, columns=possible_categories, sparse=True)
```

which yields this:

```
       Corn  Sorghum  Hemp  Cotton  Soy
0         0        0     0       0    0
1         0        0     0       0    0
2         0        0     0       0    0
3         0        0     0       0    0
4         0        0     0       0    0
    ...      ...   ...     ...  ...
35512     0        0     0       0    1
35513     0        0     0       0    1
35514     0        0     0       0    1
35515     0        0     0       0    1
35516     0        0     0       0    1

[35517 rows x 5 columns]
```

In reality, the 1st row of Crop was Cotton, Soy, Sorghum so I expected:

```
       Corn  Sorghum  Hemp  Cotton  Soy
0         0        1     0       1    1
```

I think what happened here is that get_dummies() creates dummy columns for all possible permutations of the crop data:
Corn, Cotton, Soy
Corn, Soy  Cotton  ...
Hemp, Cotton,
Soy  Hemp,
Soy  Soy
so unless the field had crops that fit into these patterns, the row gets a 0.

I'd like to specify the possible categories, split Crop into multiple columns delimited by the commas that are in the rows, and then be able to populate multiple columns if there were multiple crops grown, but I can't figure out how to make it happen. Any advice?

Comment: There are 2 functions to get dummies; in this case you almost certainly want [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) since it deals with a single Series with character delimited categories. IIUC your problem is solved with `X['Crop'].str.get_dummies(', ').reindex(possible_categories, fill_value=0, axis=1)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you.